# SurfaceHolder.Callback and SurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)

Tags: java, android

I have some code lines for an android game as below:

```
public class GameSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private GameThread gameThread;
private ChibiCharacter chibi1;

public GameSurface(Context context)  {
    super(context);

    // Make Game Surface focusable so it can handle events. .
    this.setFocusable(true);

    // Sét callback.
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Bitmap chibiBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.chibi1);
    this.chibi1 = new ChibiCharacter(this,chibiBitmap1,100,50);

    this.gameThread = new GameThread(this,holder);
    this.gameThread.setRunning(true);
    this.gameThread.start();
}
```

My first question is: What does keyword this mean in code line:

this.getholder().addCallback(**this**)

keyword **this** which parameter of addCallback(**this**)?

And my second question is: When the surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) is called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **this** refers to your class `GameSurface`. By implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback`, you need to override `surfaceCreated()`.   by adding `addCallback` you are making `surfaceCreated()` to get called when surface is created. simply put Log.i() statement & run your code to see it.

Comment: do u know how to know exactly THIS keyword refer to ?

Comment: **this** refers to current instance in which its used. for more details check https://www.guru99.com/java-this-keyword.html